# Google Cloud Speech Android Unity API Speech

Tags: unity3d, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Очень нужна помощь!

Нужно сделать распознавание речи в Android/Unity через сервис Google Cloud Speech, есть шаблон, проект был сделан год назад, сервис гугла поменялись, и теперь проблема с ключем API, не может загрузить файл wap на сервер гугла, строчка

```
string apiURL = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=" + apiKey;
```

Никогда не работал с API

Создал ключ ApiKey по видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch74M5cia7Y

Ошибка:

```
 Error uploading file error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GoogleVoiceSpeech:HttpUploadFile(String, String, String, String) (at Assets/Scripts/GoogleVoiceSpeech.cs:191)
GoogleVoiceSpeech:OnGUI() (at Assets/Scripts/GoogleVoiceSpeech.cs:130)
```

В документации на использование ключа пишут другой путь использывать
"https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key="
при попытке отправить с этим путем и моим ключем на сервер выдает ошибку:

```
WebException: Error writing request: The authentication or decryption has failed.
System.Net.WebConnectionStream.WriteHeaders ()
System.Net.WebConnectionStream.SetHeaders (System.Byte[] buffer)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebConnectionStream:SetHeaders (byte[])
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequestHeaders (Boolean propagate_error)
```

Исходник: https://github.com/steelejay/LowkeySpeech

Comment: Что за документацию вы читаете? https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/operations/get

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

Comment: То есть тебя не смущает, что ты, во-первых, обращаешься не к тому api,  во-вторых, не провел аутентификацию ?)

Comment: Всё работает, исправил) аутентификация не нужна, Speech API не был в списке, после подписки на  chromium-dev@chromium.org (https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) появился Speech API

Comment: только из-за произношения часто ошибка
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GoogleVoiceSpeech.OnGUI () (at Assets/Scripts/GoogleVoiceSpeech.cs:139)

Comment: Ну в скрипте, в 139ой строчке пытаешься обратиться к элементу, который не инициализирован, проверяй на нуль